# Trying to store multiple items in storage but only last one added gets stored

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm making an app that can be thought of as a shopping cart. A user searches for a product, they click on the product, and they have the option of adding it to their cart.
After adding the item they are brought back to the search page. However if they go back to the search page, and search for something it refreshes the page in a sense because a new HTTP request is made and if they select a product, click add, only the last product is available in storage. I believe it is being overwritten.

When the user clicks the add button `saveItem()` is called in `additems.ts`  which creates a newItem object and calls `addItem()` which is suppose to push it to the `items[]` array and save it to storage.

What am I doing wrong?

addItem.ts

```
items = [];

// params passed from another page 
name: string    = this.navParams.get('name');
desc: string    = this.navParams.get('desc');

// Called once users click on Add button in addItem.html
saveItem() {

  let newItem = {
    name: this.name,
    desc: this.desc
  };

  this.addItem(newItem);
}

addItem(item) {

  this.items.push(item);
  this.dataService.save(this.items);

  // Go back to search page. When the data is reloaded 
  // on this page it resets all of the items in storage 
  this.navCtrl.pop(Search);
}
```

addItem.html

```
<button (click)="saveItem()">Add</button>
```

DataService.ts.

```
private storage: Storage;

constructor(storage: Storage) {
  this.storage = storage;
}

getData() {
  return this.storage.get('products');
}

save(data){
  let newData = JSON.stringify(data);
  this.storage.set('products', newData);
}
```

// viewProducts.ts (This is where I want to view all current products in storage )
export class ConfirmOrderPage {

```
public items = [];

constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public modalCtrl: ModalController, public dataService: DataStorage) {

   this.dataService.getData().then((products) => {
      if(products){
        this.items = JSON.parse(products);
        console.log("confirmorder", JSON.parse(products));
      }
    });
}
```

viewProducts.html

```
ion-list>
<ion-item text-wrap *ngFor="let item of items">
  <h2>Name: {{ item.name }}</h2>
  <h3>Product Quantity: 3 </h3>
  <p>{{ item.desc }}</p>
</ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
this.storage.set('products', newData);
```

The above code will persist only one value for one key, if you want to add more items under products key consider newData value as array. Before adding a product to the local storage, retrieve the data from local storage and set it in temporary array and add the new product in that temporary array and save it in local storage. Now the products key will have array of product.

Answer (score 0):

in your .ts file, use the following code:

```
items = [];

// params passed from another page 
name: string    = this.navParams.get('name');
desc: string    = this.navParams.get('desc');

// Called once users click on Add button in addItem.html
saveItem() {

  let newItem = {
    name: this.name,
    desc: this.desc
  };

  this.dataService.save(newItem).then(()=>{
    this.navCtrl.pop(Search);
  });
}
```

and change the dataService.ts files's save() method as follows:

```
save(data): Promise<any>{
  return this.getData().then((products: any[]) => {
    products.push(data);
    return this.storage.set('products', products);
  });
}
```

Comment: I changed it to this now I'm getting this error `Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of null TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of nul` on this line `products.push(data);`

Comment: did you use ionic2 framework to create your app, if so, in your .ts file you should `import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';` and inject this storage to your `constructor()` method

NOTE: don't forget import the `IonicStorageModule` in your module file

Answer (score 0):

You cannot store multiple items under the same key. When you try to store multiple item under same key the latest one will override the previous one.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question has been written a while ago, however I had a similar problem too.  Unlike what like I expected from mysql or sqlite, these methods are  only adding one record... However, I then discovered something else rather wonderful and that it wasn't the case as expected (from the code in the link below). 
The local storage index in the browser doesn't let you change or make new index values, instead you have to use the key, then make your changes to the value.

The thing to note is that the value can have array values placed in it, of which you can then index, create, read, update and delete.

For ease of use, and without me rewriting anything, I'd suggest you take a look at Simon's answer [here from the Ionic Academy](https://ionicacademy.com/ionic-storage-crud-operations/).

Comment: this will work if the storage under the hood uses SQLite or indexeddb persistence driver, if Storage would need to fallback to localStorage it won’t work.